# Elastic Beanstalk Laravel Deployment Returns The requested URL /login was not found on this server

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, http-status-code-404, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm tying to deploy a new version of my application developed with Laravel and using Elastic Beanstalk. Once the application is deployed I get the following message on the browser: The requested URL /login was not found on this server. I tried multiple routes and all return the same. If I type /index.php/login I get to the correct page but then get back to error when the site tries to redirect to /home.

Up to this point, previous versions were all functional. I can even go back and revert to the previous version released and everything goes back to normal. Since this is the case I started analyzing what's different in these two versions. I made some changes in a couple of views, but the login view was not modified. I also added a number of routes went from 13 to 16.

This picture shows a comparison between the old and new web.php files green being the old file:

[image]

Has anyone encountered a similar error before? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the culprit for this response was an improperly named "/public/.htaccess" file. In my case the file had been renamed to "_htaccess" probably when I transferred the code from one computer to another.